# Making cartopy figure apply transform to just one axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have data in `x, z`, where `x` is longitude in degrees, and z is an altitude in km.

I'd like to be able to use Cartopy's "intelligent" handling of the longitude axis (namely, the ability to center the data at any chosen point `lon0`, which handles the data wrapping across the periodic boundary).

if my coordinates were `lat`, `lon`, this is easy, and involves sending a `projection` argument to the axis object, and a `transform` argument to the plot object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.plot(lat, lon, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I think what I need to be able to do is effectively only apply the `transform` to the x-axis. In other words, I'd like to plot vertical cross sections with the power of Cartopy, rather than the standard use case of horizontal cross sections.

Edit: perhaps all I need to is use a polar transform on the data, where $x$ is interpreted as the angular coordinate. But I would need to do this transformation *without* doing the associated projection (I still want my plot to be a rectangle, I just want to the data to behave in a period manner)

Comment: You need to use `Blended transformations`  https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html .

Comment: @swatchai Thanks, this looks promising. It looks like this requires me to create an `x_transform` object to pass to `blended_transform_factory`. It is not yet clear to me how to construct this object. Please post some more info if you have some know-how

Comment: Please post small representative data set and sample output plot(s) or sketches that you want as the output. Data will be used in the code. Plots/sketches will help the readers to understand more exactly what the requirements are.

Comment: This is another useful link:  https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/scales/scales.html

Comment: @swatchai I actually made a new question that is more precise, and had example code and data, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71935036/plotting-in-polar-space-in-matplotlib